# How to change background color of JOptionPane?

Tags: java, swing, background-color, joptionpane

I have added JOptionPane to my application but I do not know how to change background color to white?

```
`int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(bcfiDownloadPanel,
            new Object[]{"Host: " + source, panel},
            "Authorization Required",
            JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE
    );

    if (option == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {                  }`
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

By using the [`UIManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html) class

```
 import javax.swing.UIManager;

 UIManager UI=new UIManager();
 UI.put("OptionPane.background",new ColorUIResource(255,0,0));
 UI.put("Panel.background",new ColorUIResource(255,0,0));
```

or

```
 UIManager UI=new UIManager();
 UI.put("OptionPane.background", Color.white);
 UI.put("Panel.background", Color.white);

 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Text","SetColor",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: Note that this will change the background for all instances.

Comment: Is it possible to add my custom button to it also?

Answer (score 4):

[image: JOptionPane image]

For anyone having the same problem like above image, I found/adapted a solution. On my system, I got that result, whether I used the UIManager solution as others have posted, or made a JDialog and used `jd.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white)`. So here is the work-around I came up with, where you loop recursively through each component in the JOptionPane, and set each JPanel's background color:

```
private void getComponents(Container c){

    Component[] m = c.getComponents();

    for(int i = 0; i < m.length; i++){

        if(m[i].getClass().getName() == "javax.swing.JPanel")
            m[i].setBackground(Color.white);

        if(c.getClass().isInstance(m[i]))
            getComponents((Container)m[i]);
    }
}
```

In your code where you want to have the message pop-up, something along the lines of:

```
pane = new JOptionPane("Your message here", 
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE ,JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION);
        getComponents(pane);
        pane.setBackground(Color.white);
        jd = pane.createDialog(this, "Message");
        jd.setVisible(true);
```

Where `JOptionPane pane` and `JDialog jd` have previously been created. Hope this helps anyone who had that issue.

Comment: This is the best response

Answer (score 2):

Use something like this to change the background color just for this one message display and not the whole system...

```
    Object paneBG = UIManager.get("OptionPane.background");
    Object panelBG = UIManager.get("Panel.background");
    UIManager.put("OptionPane.background", new Color(...));
    UIManager.put("Panel.background", new Color(...));

    int ret = messageBox(msg, null, (short)type);

    UIManager.put("OptionPane.background", paneBG);
    UIManager.put("Panel.background", panelBG);
```

Comment: What is the method "messageBox()"?

Answer (score 2):

Use this code if you have the same problem as erik k atwood. This solves the problem:

```
UIManager.put("OptionPane.background", Color.WHITE);
UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Panel.background", Color.WHITE);
```

Answer (score 1):

UIManager.put("OptionPane.background", Color.WHITE);
UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Panel.background", Color.WHITE);

Put this code before you call your JOptionPane dialog like:

```
UIManager.put("OptionPane.background", Color.decode("#3c6562"));
UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Panel.background", Color.decode("#3c6562"));
    
int input= JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog
(
   null,
   "Close the programm?",
   "Exit",
   JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION
 );

 if(input == 0)
 {
    System.exit(0);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In nimbus look and feel these all codes are not usable.

So solution is,

```
UIManager.put("control", new Color(0, 0, 0));
```

This is also call "Dark Nimbus" add this top of your main frame's main method.
So it will automatically change All JOptionPane's background.

And also you can't change button background with

```
UIManager.put("OptionPane.buttonBackground", BLACK);
```

So you should use,

```
UIManager.put("nimbusBase", new Color(0, 0, 0));
```

Remember - but unfortunately, this code will change all your buttons etcs' background. So you have to add `*.setBackground(...);` to all other objects.

If you want to change foreground of JOptionPane you should use

```
UIManager.put("text", new Color(255, 255, 255));
```

Again unfortunately this will change your all of text's foreground.

These all codes are called Dark Nimbus.

If you're using nimbus you can try these UIManager codes to customize nimbus look and feel.

```
UIManager.put("control", new Color(0, 0, 0));
UIManager.put("info", new Color(0, 0, 0));
UIManager.put("nimbusBase", new Color(0, 0, 0));
UIManager.put("nimbusAlertYellow", new Color(248, 187, 0));
UIManager.put("nimbusDisabledText", new Color(255, 255, 255));
UIManager.put("nimbusFocus", new Color(115, 164, 209));
UIManager.put("nimbusGreen", new Color(176, 179, 50));
UIManager.put("nimbusInfoBlue", new Color(66, 139, 221));
UIManager.put("nimbusLightBackground", new Color(0, 0, 0));
UIManager.put("nimbusOrange", new Color(191, 98, 4));
UIManager.put("nimbusRed", new Color(169, 46, 34));
UIManager.put("nimbusSelectedText", new Color(255, 255, 255));
UIManager.put("nimbusSelectionBackground", new Color(18, 134, 175));
UIManager.put("text", new Color(255, 255, 255));
```

You can try these codes. In my project the nimbus seem as

[image]

[image]

[image]

But I always recommend using "Flatleaf" (Search google "FlatLafLookAndFeel" or go to jar.download.com"). It is a professional and you can change all to your own.