# JOptionPane with different background

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I'm trying to change background color of my JOptionPane through UIManager constants, the backgrounds of the text area and the button area are not affected.

I have posted my code :3
[image]

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05wtq.jpg)

How can I modify their backgrounds too?

```
public LoginFINAL() {
    this.setImagen("/imagenes/FondoLogin.png");
    UIManager.put("OptionPane.background",Color.RED );  
    UIManager.put("Panel.background",Color.RED);  
    UIManager.put("Button.background",Color.RED); 
    initComponents();
    jLabel3.setVisible(false);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    textUsers.requestFocus();


}
```

And this is how i call the JoptionPane

```
else{
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "pls");

    }
```

Is it better now?

Comment: The background of the Message and the button should be blue

Comment: is the picture your code?

Comment: Yeah it is... after that im calling JoptionPane to show this message... If you need more code, just tell me what you want to see

Comment: Same result... mmm i took a photo of the part where the look and feel is set to the main class... Does it help?

http://imgur.com/TQ1Cs7V

Comment: I still do not know how you got this pic because I did it in my pc and everything turns to blue. 
could you share all your code plz?

Comment: As @KickButtowski points out, he's getting a different result than you.  Please include an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to allow us to recreate your problem exactly as you have encountered it.

Comment: i do not understand it. can you please clarify?

Comment: @user3579230 An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) should be very short, simple, and self-contained. The code you've included is far too large for anyone to realistically want to understand it and help.

Comment: I don't know so i think that the problem is when the LookandFell starts... because if i comment the part where the look and feel set the parameters... it turns totally blue,.... Any idea?

Comment: Great question! I think somebody answered it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9064943/how-to-change-background-color-of-joptionpane (Note to people who just say "Possible duplicate"- that doesn't make the asker feel welcome. Be more considerate in the future).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change background color of JOptionPane?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9064943/how-to-change-background-color-of-joptionpane)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, here is my solution:

[JOptionPane image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4PXq.png)

For anyone having the problem in the image, I found/adapted a solution. On my system, I got that result, whether I used the UIManager solution as others have posted, or made a JDialog and used jd.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white). So here is the work-around I came up with, where you loop recursively through each component in the JOptionPane, and set each JPanel's background color:

```
private void getComponents(Container c){

    Component[] m = c.getComponents();

    for(int i = 0; i < m.length; i++){

        if(m[i].getClass().getName() == "javax.swing.JPanel")
            m[i].setBackground(Color.white);

        if(c.getClass().isInstance(m[i]));
            getComponents((Container)m[i]);
    }
}
```

In your code where you want to have the message pop-up, something along the lines of:

```
pane = new JOptionPane("Your message here", 
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE ,JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION);
        getComponents(pane);
        pane.setBackground(Color.white);
        jd = pane.createDialog(this, "Message");
        jd.setVisible(true);
```

Where `JOptionPane pane` and `JDialog jd` have previously been created. Hope this helps anyone who had that issue.

Comment: How do we change the background color of the message? It did change the pane and panel.