# How to change background color of JOptionPane without using UIManager?

Tags: java, joptionpane

I'm trying to change the background color of a JOptionPane but this code didnt work.

```
JOptionPane jOptionPane1 = new JOptionPane( );
jOptionPane1.showMessageDialog(this, "Επιτυχής καταχώρηση");
jOptionPane1.setBackground(Color.white);
```

But why?

(I understand that JOptionPane is a static method and theres no need to create a new object, and that i can just import the UIManager to get the job done.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your problem.

```
JOptionPane op = new JOptionPane("message", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION); 
     op.setOpaque(true);
     op.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
     op.createDialog(this, "Titel").setVisible(true);
```

If not, you should have a look on this workaround [JOptionPane with different background](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37799905/6025616)