# UIManager class does not change JOptionPane Background Fully

Tags: java, swing

I had to change the background color of JoptionPane so with the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9064943/how-to-change-background-color-of-joptionpane) i did it.But I was Partially successful as the color of area around the text was not changed(button too).Here is the link of it
http://tinypic.com/r/14mghw1/8
 .What should i do it to apply the changes to whole JoptionPane.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Panel.background should have worked....but you're using Nimbus L&F which does it's own things

Comment: @MadProgrammer using Netbeans 8.

Comment: Netbeans should have no effect on it

Comment: @madProgrammer what should i do?

Comment: a solution to this problem can be found here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30298489/