# showInputDialog Formatting

Tags: java, look-and-feel, showdialog

I'm trying to figure out Java's JOptionPane.showInputDialog look and feel,
more specifically, the commented line below:

```
final JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
    dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);  
 // OptionPane.background("blue");
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(dialog, "Dialog");
```

How do I correctly use that line?

Comment: Please mark the answer once its has helped your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should try this

```
dialog.getContentPane().setBackground( Color.blue );
```

Comment: for JOption Pane see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9064943/how-to-change-background-color-of-joptionpane