# Swing JOptionPane background color is different

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, uimanager

I have been trying to display a messagebox in Swing with `JOptionPane` by using:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Component parentComponent,
                                     Object message,
                                     String title,
                                     int messageType)
                              throws HeadlessException
```

The message box looks as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssbZn.png):

[image]

When I add this line

```
UIManager.put("OptionPane.background", Color.white);
```

Option pane looks as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odwJU.png):

[image]

What should I do in order to get a pure white background in the message box?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the panel background also white. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9064970/1966247)

```
     UIManager UI = new UIManager();
     UI.put("OptionPane.background", Color.white);
     UI.put("Panel.background", Color.white);
```

**Update**

I have the following code and it is working fine for me.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import java.awt.Color;

public class Dialog {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        UIManager.put("OptionPane.background", Color.WHITE);
        UIManager.put("OptionPane.messagebackground", Color.WHITE);
        UIManager.put("Panel.background", Color.WHITE);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Com Port!", "SetColor", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

[**Here**](http://thebadprogrammer.com/swing-uimanager-keys/) is a list of the keys for the UIManager
[image]

Comment: Didn't help me. Any other suggestion please

Comment: @LakshmiNarasimhanRavichandran copy my updated code and test it.

Comment: @Muhammd That too didn't help either. Sorry about that!!

Comment: @LakshmiNarasimhanRavichandran I have updated my code a bit more, please try it.

Comment: public void ShowMessage(final String message)
 {
 Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
 public void run(){
          UIManager UI=new UIManager();
    UIManager.put("OptionPane.background", Color.WHITE);
    UIManager.put("Panel.background", Color.WHITE);
    UIManager.put("OptionPane.messagebackground", Color.WHITE);
    
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frmStrykerVer, message, Error_Title, Error_Message);
          
         }
     });
   t.start();
 }

Comment: that too didn't help.